# Getting error with itemize and column using in succession

Tags: beamer, itemize, columns

In my presentation, I need to put two graphs under a list item. I am trying the following code but am getting an error stating that "Missing number, treated as zero. \end{frame}". If I remove this piece of code, it works fine. The piece of code is;

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Simulation Results \& Observations}
\begin{itemize}
    \item NCMSE based analysis of SiT-OMP \& SiT-CoSaMP with variations in Sparsity (S)
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{width=0.5\textwidth}
        Here is something.
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{width=0.5\textwidth}
        Here is something.
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is `width=` in `\begin{column}{width=0.5\textwidth}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Simulation Results \& Observations}
\begin{itemize}
    \item NCMSE based analysis of SiT-OMP \& SiT-CoSaMP with variations in Sparsity (S)
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
        Here is something.
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
        Here is something.
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Decreased the width a tiny bit to prevent the second row from running over the frame. Big thanks to @samcarter!

Comment: Nice answer! Just a tiny suggestion: I would either use `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]` or `\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}`. Otherwise the columns will spill over into the margin.